# how to tar files with long name/long path

Tags: unix, tar, filenames

When I tar files with long path name, the file name is converted to "637",
and the file doesn't exists in the packing file.
I try to use gtar, with no successful.
Do I need specific version of tar/gtar?
(It has to work on every OS/Platform).

Comment: Not a programming question, voting for close (move to Superuser).

Comment: Can you post that 'long path name'? What platform are you using?

Comment: @unwind: probably not superuser but unix.SE?

Comment: @9000: Depends on platform. Tar and a reasonable shell can cope with a lot of filename abuse, I'd guess the shell is a likely culprit here (from that, my guesses: Cygwin? cmd.exe? Ancient make of `sh`?)